# Why can't I access my AWS EKS deployment/service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, network-programming

I have an AWS EKS cluster, in which there are two pods running: one for a redis cache, and the other for a GraphQL API.

Now I will present the config files for my kubernetes cluster.

`cache-deployment.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: chatto-cache-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: cache
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: cache
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: cache-container
          image: redis
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 512Mi
              cpu: "1"
            requests:
              memory: 256Mi
              cpu: "0.2"
```

`cache-service.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: chatto-cache-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    tier: cache
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
```

`server-deployment.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: chatto-server-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server-container
          image: rocketblast2481/chatto-server
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 512Mi
              cpu: "1"
            requests:
              memory: 256Mi
              cpu: "0.2"
          env:
            - name: DB_USERNAME
              valueFrom: 
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: env-config-map
                  key: DB_USERNAME
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom: 
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: env-config-map
                  key: DB_PASSWORD
            - name: DB_HOST
              valueFrom: 
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: env-config-map
                  key: DB_HOST
            - name: DB_PORT
              valueFrom: 
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: env-config-map
                  key: DB_PORT
            - name: DB_DATABASE
              valueFrom: 
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: env-config-map
                  key: DB_DATABASE
            - name: REDIS_HOST
              valueFrom: 
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: env-config-map
                  key: REDIS_HOST
            - name: REDIS_PORT
              valueFrom: 
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: env-config-map
                  key: REDIS_PORT
```

`server-service.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: chatto-server-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    tier: server
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Okay, here's the problem. As you can see, the `server-service` is of type `LoadBalancer`.

When I run the command, `kubectl get services`, this is the output:

```
NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP                                                              PORT(S)        AGE
chatto-cache-service    ClusterIP      10.100.73.117   <none>                                                                   6379/TCP       5h17m
chatto-server-service   LoadBalancer   10.100.11.249   afe3adae38c0242c8be0795609ee8a6c-424128423.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com   80:31643/TCP   17m
kubernetes              ClusterIP      10.100.0.1      <none>                                                                   443/TCP        6h35m
```

I copied the EXTERNAL-IP of the chatto-server-service and slapped it into Postman, but I get an error that the connection refused.

Could someone tell me why this might be happening? It might be because of the way I have configured the security groups, but I don't know for sure.

Thanks for any feedback and help and please let me know if you need any other information.

**Edit:**

Here is a screenshot of the load balancer:

[image]

Comment: Can you go to AWS console and check this ALB? afe3adae38c0242c8be0795609ee8a6c-424128423.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com
I think it's because of security groups

Comment: How should I configure my security groups?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your ALB? If it's okay, you can open the ALB to internet by allow 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Sorry if the screenshot doesn't give you enough information, I wasn't sure which part you wanted to see

Comment: Quick note: There is a button called "Migrate" - would that solve it?

Comment: No, you don't need to. In your image, I see 0 of 2 instances in service. So your ALB does not point to your cluster successfully.

Comment: Are you sure the chatto-server-deployment pod is running correctly? Have you checked using port-forwarding (`kubectl port-forward`)?

Comment: @Ash Blake What can I do to make my ALB point to my cluster?

Comment: Actually, I need to check the console because there are a lot of reason cause it. You can change to another way: Change the chatto-server-service to Nodeport, and create the ALB independently and point to that Nodeport

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I will keep trying

Comment: Can you paste the output of `kubectl get pods` in your question?